# Pandas row analysis for consecutive dates

Tags: python, date, csv, pandas

Following a "chain" of rows and counting the consecutive months from a CSV file.

Currently I am reading a CSV file with 5 columns of interest (based on insurance policies):

```
CONTRACT_ID   START-DATE           END-DATE        CANCEL_FLAG    OLD_CON_ID
123456        2015-05-30           2016-05-30       0             8788
123457        2014-03-20           2015-03-20       0             12000
123458        2009-12-20           2010-12-20       0             NaN
...
```

I want to count the number of consecutive months a Contract chain goes for.

Example: Taking the `START-DATE` from the contract at the "front" of the chain (oldest contract) and the `END-DATE` from the end of the chain (newest contract). Oldest contract being defined by either the one *before* a cancelled contract in a chain or the one that has no `OLD_CON_ID` value.

Each row represents a contract and the prev_Con_ID points to the previous contract ID. The desired output is how many months the contract chains goes back until a gap (i.e. customer didn't have a contract for a period of time). If nothing in that column then that is the first contract in this chain.

CANCEL_FLAG should also cut the chain because a value of 1 designates that the contract was cancelled.

Current code counts the number of active contracts for each year by editing the dataframe like so:

```
df_contract = df_contract[
(df_contract['START_DATE'] <= pd.to_datetime('2015-05-31')) & 
(df_contract['END_DATE'] >= pd.to_datetime('2015-05-31')) & (df_contract['CANCEL_FLAG'] == 0 )
]
df_contract = df_contract[df_contract['CANCEL_FLAG'] == 0
]
activecount = df_contract.count()
print activecount['CONTRACT_ID']
```

Here are the first 6 lines of code in which I create the dataframes and adjust the datetime values:

```
file_name = 'EXAMPLENAME.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(file_name)
df_contract = pd.read_csv(file_name)
df_CUSTOMERS = pd.read_csv(file_name)

df_contract['START_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df_contract['START_DATE'])
df_contract['END_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df_contract['END_DATE'])
```

Ideal output is something like:

```
FIRST_CONTRACT_ID       CHAIN_LENGTH       CON_MONTHS
1234567                 5                  60
1500001                 1                  4
800                     10                 180
```

Those data points would then be graphed.

EDIT2: CSV file changed, might be easier now. Question updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error I got it working!

This finds the time difference between the first and last contracts in the chain **and** finds the length of the chain.

Not the cleanest code by far, but it works:

```
test = 'START_DATE'


df_short = df_policy[['OLD_CON_ID',test,'CONTRACT_ID']]
df_short.rename(columns={'OLD_CON_ID':'PID','CONTRACT_ID':'CID'}, 

inplace = True)
df_test = df_policy[['CONTRACT_ID','END_DATE']]
df_test.rename(columns={'CONTRACT_ID':'CID','END_DATE': 'PED'}, inplace = True)


df_copy1 = df_short.copy()
df_copy2 = df_short.copy()
df_copy2.rename(columns={'PID':'PPID','CID':'PID'}, inplace = True)

df_merge1 = pd.merge(df_short, df_copy2,
    how='left',
    on=['PID'])

df_merge1['START_DATE_y'].fillna(df_merge1['START_DATE_x'], inplace = True)
df_merge1.rename(columns={'START_DATE_x':'1_EFF','START_DATE_y':'2_EFF'}, inplace=True)
```

The copy, merge, fillna, and rename code is repeated for 5 merged dataframes then:

```
df_merged = pd.merge(df_merge5, df_test,
    how='right',
    on=['CID'])

df_merged['TOTAL_MONTHS'] = ((df_merged['PED'] - df_merged['6_EFF']
                             )/np.timedelta64(1,'M'))

df_merged4 = df_merged[
    (df_merged['PED'] >= pd.to_datetime('2015-07-06')) 
df_merged4['CHAIN_LENGTH'] = df_merged4.drop(['PED','1_EFF','2_EFF','3_EFF','4_EFF','5_EFF'], axis=1).apply(lambda row: len(pd.unique(row)), axis=1) -3
```

Hopefully my code is understood and will help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I totally undertand your requirement, but does something like this work?:

```
df_contract['TOTAL_YEARS'] = (df_contract['END_DATE'] - df_contract['START_DATE']
                             )/np.timedelta64(1,'Y')

df_contract['TOTAL_YEARS'][(df['CANCEL_FLAG'] == 1) && (df['TOTAL_YEARS'] > 1)] = 1
```

Comment: Took me way too long to verify, but it is correctly counting the # of years of being customer, though not consecutive. To explain with example. Client1 had a contract from 2006 to 2008, then 2010 to 2015. The code should return a 5 then, as opposed to a 9.

Comment: Also I edited the original question because of a change with original CSV file. Hopefully this makes it easier to understand (and execute).