# Count null/NaN values in a dataframe across columns

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, nan

I'm trying to count the number of unique values for each row across the columns of a dataframe.

[More context in my previous post and my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31127870/pandas-row-analysis-for-consecutive-dates/31236278#31236278)

Here is the current dataframe:

```
[in] df
[out] 
         PID         CID      PPID        PPPID       PPPPID        PPPPPID
    0   2015-01-02   456      2014-01-02  2014-01-02  2014-01-02    2014-01-02
    1   2015-02-02   500      2014-02-02  2013-02-02  2012-02-02    2012-02-10  
    2   2010-12-04   300      2010-12-04  2010-12-04  2010-12-04    2010-12-04
```

All columns except CID (contract_ID) are datetimes. I'd like to add another column to the dataframe that counts the number of unique datetimes in each row (for the purpose of finding out how many contracts there are in a "chain").

I've tried different implementations of the `.count()` and  `.sum()` methods but can't get them to work on a row-by-row basis (output is all rows with the same value).

Example:

```
df_merged['COUNT'] = df_merged2.count(axis=1)
```

Fills the entire 'COUNT' column with '6' when I'd like to be different for each row.

Removing the `axis=1` argument makes the entire column 'NaN'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `apply(your_func, axis=1)` to work on a row-by-row basis.

```
df

Out[19]: 
          PID  CID        PPID       PPPID      PPPPID     PPPPPID
0  2015-01-02  456  2014-01-02  2014-01-02  2014-01-02  2014-01-02
1  2015-02-02  500  2014-02-02  2013-02-02  2012-02-02  2012-02-10
2  2010-12-04  300  2010-12-04  2010-12-04  2010-12-04  2010-12-04



df['counts'] = df.drop('CID', axis=1).apply(lambda row: len(pd.unique(row)), axis=1)

Out[20]: 
          PID  CID        PPID       PPPID      PPPPID     PPPPPID  counts
0  2015-01-02  456  2014-01-02  2014-01-02  2014-01-02  2014-01-02       2
1  2015-02-02  500  2014-02-02  2013-02-02  2012-02-02  2012-02-10       5
2  2010-12-04  300  2010-12-04  2010-12-04  2010-12-04  2010-12-04       1

[3 rows x 7 columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to call [`unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unique.html#pandas.Series.unique) on the transpose of your df:

```
In [26]:    
df['counts'] = df.drop('CID', axis=1).T.apply(lambda x: len(pd.Series.unique(x)))
df

Out[26]:
          PID  CID        PPID       PPPID      PPPPID     PPPPPID  counts
0  2015-01-02  456  2014-01-02  2014-01-02  2014-01-02  2014-01-02       2
1  2015-02-02  500  2014-02-02  2013-02-02  2012-02-02  2012-02-10       5
2  2010-12-04  300  2010-12-04  2010-12-04  2010-12-04  2010-12-04       1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use `nunique` on `DataFrame`. This is from `pd.__version__ == u'0.20.0'` onwards.

```
In [169]: df['counts'] = df.drop('CID', axis=1).nunique(axis=1)

In [170]: df
Out[170]:
          PID  CID        PPID       PPPID      PPPPID     PPPPPID  counts
0  2015-01-02  456  2014-01-02  2014-01-02  2014-01-02  2014-01-02       2
1  2015-02-02  500  2014-02-02  2013-02-02  2012-02-02  2012-02-10       5
2  2010-12-04  300  2010-12-04  2010-12-04  2010-12-04  2010-12-04       1
```